# r markdown, knitr and latex symbols

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

After several hours of searching for an answer to no avail, I thought I'd seek advice here.

I'm trying to produce some very simple html tables using knitr in r markdown, but I can't get the latex symbols to display correctly in the column names.

Example code, with several different symbols:

```
kable(data.frame("$^3$" = "a",
                  "$\\epsilon^2$" = "b",
                  "$%$" = "c"),
                  escape = F)
```

[image: Here's the output]

As you can see the column names are not formatted `X..3.` `X..epsilon.2.` `X...`

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: which packages are using to achieve this?

Comment: knitr and base r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use those column names in a data frame, but you need to tell the `data.frame` function not to mangle them using `check.names = FALSE`.
However, this isn't enough to fix your example, because `$%$` is not legal LaTeX.
You need to escape the percent sign or it will be taken to be a comment character.
So this works:

```
my_data <- data.frame("$^3$" = "a",
                      "$\\epsilon^2$" = "b",
                      "$\\%$" = "c",
                      check.names = FALSE)
kable(my_data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `col.names` in your `kable`-call. It does not work in your `data.frame`-call, because that does not allow column names which don't start with a dot or letter. 
You can see this here:

```
my_data <- data.frame("$^3$" = "a",
                      "$\\epsilon^2$" = "b",
                      "$%$" = "c")
my_data
  X..3. X..epsilon.2. X...
1     a             b    c
```

The solution is:

```
kable(my_data, escape = F, 
      col.names = c("$^3$", "$\\epsilon^2$", "$%$"))
```

[image]

You might want to use `\varepsilon` instead of `\epsilon` as this gives a prettier epsilon (in my opinion).

```
kable(my_data, escape = F, 
      col.names = c("$^3$", "$\\varepsilon^2$", "$%$"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware the data frame caused these kind of issues. Cheers for the varepsilon tip too!